Trino in docker container, Database in docker container, Trino cannot list tables
I've set up trino in a docker container, following the documentation: https://trino.io/docs/current/installation/containers.html. This works fine.
Then I've added a docker container with a MySQL server and another one with a MS SQL Server. These also work fine.
I can query both in their initial states through Dbeaver.
To Trino I've also mapped a volume on my host and added the catalogs to the two databases above. These also show up in Trino.
It all looks like this in DBeaver:

The problem is that Trino won't query the schemas nor the tables of the two databases. In the CLI I get these results:



The error messages are different, but the result is the same. The database connections both work, I can query them in Dbeaver. So I'm not really sure, where the problem ist.

In the trino properties file try changing the connection-url from using localhost to host.docker.internal
